# Incomplete *.rar works on VLC but not on libVLC

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to play an incomplete rar file using libVLC with python bindings.
If I run the following command from the console I get some errors but I can see the video on VLC.

```
VLC media player 2.0.5 Twoflower (revision 2.0.5-0-g1661b7d)
[0x652108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x7fde50c02028] filesystem access error: cannot open file /tmp/incomplete.r01 (No such file or directory)
[0x7fde50001438] main stream error: no suitable access module for `file:///tmp/incomplete.r01'
[0x8732e8] main playlist: stopping playback
[0x7fde50c0d5c8] filesystem access error: cannot open file /tmp/incomplete.r01 (No such file or directory)
[0x7fde50c018d8] main stream error: no suitable access module for `file:///tmp/incomplete.r01'
[0x7fde400505c8] freetype spu text error: Breaking unbreakable line
```

But If I run the video using the python bindings it doesn't work.

```
import vlc, time
instance = vlc.Instance()
media=instance.media_new('/tmp/incomplete.rar')
player=instance.media_player_new()
player.set_media(media)
player.play()

time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
[0x7f523800a0d8] filesystem access error: cannot open file /tmp/incomplete.r01 (No such file or directory)
[0x7f523800a0d8] main access error: File reading failed
[0x7f523800a0d8] main access error: VLC could not open the file "/tmp/incomplete.r01". (No such file or directory)
[0x7f5238006638] main stream error: no suitable access module for `/tmp/incomplete.r01'
```

I think that VLC uses some default options that the libVLC doesn't. Any help on this is appreciated.